# Update property value with changes made in registry during install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX project in which there is a need to check for certain registry keys that should be added as part of install.
But using the RegistrySearch element, as it is scheduled with AppSearch execute sequence, I always end up getting a blank value because till AppSearch no keys are written.

Is there any way I can determine existence of Registry keys somewhere around PostInstall?

This question is somewhat similar to : [this question](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Search-registry-key-at-the-end-of-installation-td7581214.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a search to see if a registry from the package is installed or not? You could simply just check the [state of its component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx). If the state say the component got installed it means the registry is on the machine, and vice versa.

[Condition examples.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368561(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Checking the registry occurs via AppSearch. That is not where i want it to occur, besides it should happen post install. Also i do not want to terminate my installation if the registry is not found.